# unable to get async message using activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic

hello everyone i am unable to recieve asynchronous message using active mq, below code which i am using for publish message and subscribe it.

```
    public class publishMessage extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

       InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) envContext.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start() ;
            Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("jms/topic/MyQueue");
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT) ;
            TextMessage msg=session.createTextMessage();
            msg.setText("Message sent");
                    System.out.println("Message Sent");
            producer.send(msg);
            session.commit() ;
            connection.close() ;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace() ;
            }
    }}


class Consumer{

    protected Queue queue;


    protected String queueName = "jms/topic/MyQueue";

    protected String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

    protected int ackMode = Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer rec=new Consumer();
        try {
            rec.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() throws JMSException{

        System.out.println("URL:" + url);
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        TopicConnection connection = (TopicConnection)connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        connection.setClientID("Testingconn1") ;
        connection.start();
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queue = session.createQueue(queueName) ;
        consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        consumer.setMessageListener(new MyListener()) ;
        session.commit() ;
        consumer.close();
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    }

}

package com.java;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class MyListener implements MessageListener{

    @Override
    public void onMessage( final Message message )
    {
        if ( message instanceof TextMessage )
        {
            final TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Listener:" +  textMessage.getText() );
            }
            catch (final JMSException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

when i am executing the above code, publisher successfully send a message and the output comes as required when i start my consumer, no output comes into my console.

pl help me to resolve it or suggest a code to receive async message.

Answer (score 1):

Your consumer code doesn't actually give the consumer any time to consume the message.  An async consumer is used when the consumer will live on for some time and your app can process the incoming messages.  In the above code you'd be better off using the timed receive method from MessageConsumer e.g. consumer.receive(5000) or some such suitable time period for you app.  You consumer is not guaranteed to get a message immediately upon creation as it takes time for the broker to register the consumer and route a message to it, so you have to allow for that in your app.

Comment: Yeah the message listener is to be used if you want to keep receiving messages, alike a EJB MDB. Where as if you want to only receive a single message, then use the receive method on the consumer. Also with the message listener, you should only close the session/consumer etc when you do not want the listener to run any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Your consumer class is correct. It runs smoothly.

But, you consumer is incorrect & you have to modify it.

- First, add setClientID("any_string_value") after creating connection object;

  ```
   eg: Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
      // need to setClientID value, any string value you wish
      connection.setClientID("12345");
  ```

  - secondly, use createDurableSubscriber() method instead of createConsumer() for transmitting message via topic.

    ```
     MessageConsumer consumer = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic,"SUB1234");
    ```

Here is the modified comsumer class:

```
package mq.test;

import javax.jms.*;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class consumer {
    // URL of the JMS server
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

    // Name of the topic from which we will receive messages from = " testt"

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        // Getting JMS connection from the server

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

        // need to setClientID value, any string value you wish
        connection.setClientID("12345");

        try{
        connection.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("NOT CONNECTED!!!");
        }
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Topic topic = session.createTopic("test_data");

        //need to use createDurableSubscriber() method instead of createConsumer() for topic
        // MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic,
                "SUB1234");

        MessageListener listner = new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                try {
                    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                        System.out.println("Received message"
                                + textMessage.getText() + "'");
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    System.out.println("Caught:" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        consumer.setMessageListener(listner);
        //connection.close();

    }
}
```